# Getting an "AttributeError" when trying to use a class function that calls another function from that class inside a second class

Tags: python, function, object

I am writing a small program that uses pickle to let people locally save their timetable/paysheet to their computer.

I have the following class:

```
class ScheduleDataService:

    def create_object_path(self, active_user):

        users_object_path = root / "user_objects" / active_user
        return users_object_path

    def save_users_schedule(self, users_schedule, users_object_path, active_user):
        schedule = open(users_object_path, "wb")
        pickle.dump(users_schedule, schedule)
        schedule.close()

        logger.debug("\nYour schedule has been successfully saved \n")
        logger.info(active_user + "has successfully saved their schedule.")

    def load_users_schedule(self, active_user):
        users_object_path = self.create_object_path(active_user)
        schedule = open(users_object_path, "rb")
        users_schedule = pickle.load(schedule)
        schedule.close()

        return users_schedule
```

Inside this class I call the class function "create_object_path" inside of the class function "load_users_schedule".

Inside of the same module I have a second class used for viewing a users current schedule:

```
class ViewSchedule:

    __schedule_data_service: ScheduleDataService

    def __init__(self, schedule_data_service):
        self.__schedule_data_service = schedule_data_service

    def view_day(self, day_to_see, active_user):
        users_schedule = self.__schedule_data_service.load_users_schedule(self, active_user)


        to_view = []

        if day_to_see == "1":
            to_view.append("Monday")
        elif day_to_see == "2":
            to_view.append("Tuesday")
        elif day_to_see == "3":
            to_view.append("Wednesday")
        elif day_to_see == "4":
            to_view.append("Thursday")
        elif day_to_see == "5":
            to_view.append("Friday")
        elif day_to_see.lower() == "all":
            to_view = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
        else:
            logger.debug("Sorry that isn't a valid option please try again")
            logger.info(active_user + "failed to view " + day_to_see + " from their schedule due to incorrect input")
            pass

        for day in users_schedule.week:
            if day.name in to_view:
                logger.debug("")
                for session in day.sessions:
                    logger.debug("Day: " + day.name + " Class Code: " + session.code + " Class length: "
                                 + session.length)
                logger.debug("")
```

I am trying to give this class is own instance of the class above. I am then trying to call the "load_users_schedule" function to load the users schedule. When I do this I get the following error.

```
File "generator.py", line 116, in <module>
    ViewSchedule(ScheduleDataService).view_day(day_to_see, active_user)
  File "/shared/projects/pay_sheet_generator/schedule_data.py", line 249, in view_day
    users_schedule = self.__schedule_data_service.load_users_schedule(self, active_user)
  File "/shared/projects/pay_sheet_generator/schedule_data.py", line 40, in load_users_schedule
    users_object_path = self.create_object_path(active_user)
AttributeError: 'ViewSchedule' object has no attribute 'create_object_path'
```

When I remove "create_object_path" from "load_users_schedule" and run them independently the code works without issue. What I am looking for is a way to be able to embed functions inside of each other as seen above, or an explanation as to why I shouldn't do it.

Edit:

The call to ViewSchedule looks like this

```
ViewSchedule(ScheduleDataService).view_day(day_to_see, active_user)
```

Comment: Can you add how you create an object of `ViewSchedule`? Also why are you using a dunder variable `__schedule_data_service`?

Comment: On the call to `self.__schedule_data_service.load_users_schedule(self, active_user)` - you don't need to pass `self`. In general, you almost never need to pass `self`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I have added the call to ViewSchedule that happens in the main flow of the program that is triggering the error.

I listed it as a dunder variable as I wanted it seen as private are not an area to play around with.

Comment: You should be aware of name mangling with dunder variable, instead use a single underscore

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh

Thanks. Ill make the adjustment.

Comment: Also why are you not using an instance of `ScheduleDataService` to pass to `ViewSchedule` constructor? essentially `ViewSchedule(ScheduleDataService()).view_day(day_to_see, active_user)`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh

Because I am a silly silly man. Also you just solved my issue. I made that change and the code now runs as intended. Thank you very much. If you make a post explaining the error I will be sure to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @EyalH

After fixing my issue with not calling an instance of ScheduleDataService I no longer need to call self. Thanks.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh

Sums it up very well. Thank you again for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code.

1. On the line `users_schedule = self.__schedule_data_service.load_users_schedule(self, active_user)`, you do not need to add `self` as the first argument, because when you call an method of a class with the instance, the first argument is automatically inserted the instance of that class
2. You need to pass an instance of `ScheduleDataService` to the instance of `ViewSchedule`, so you would want to do `ViewSchedule(ScheduleDataService()).view_day(day_to_see, active_user)` instead of `ViewSchedule(ScheduleDataService).view_day(day_to_see, active_user)`
3. Also you should be aware than dunder variables are [name-mangled](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) in python, hence use them carefully in your class

Answer (score 1):

This kinda does what you want.  It's helpful if people can copy and run your code.  You have several variables and imports not included in your code.

```
import pickle
import logging

root = ""
logger = logging.getLogger()


class ScheduleDataService:

    def create_object_path(self, active_user):

        users_object_path = root + "user_objects" + active_user
        return users_object_path

    def save_users_schedule(self, users_schedule, users_object_path, active_user):
        schedule = open(users_object_path, "wb")
        pickle.dump(users_schedule, schedule)
        schedule.close()

        logger.debug("\nYour schedule has been successfully saved \n")
        logger.info(active_user + "has successfully saved their schedule.")

    def load_users_schedule(self, active_user):
        users_object_path = self.create_object_path(active_user)
        schedule = open(users_object_path, "rb")
        users_schedule = pickle.load(schedule)
        schedule.close()

        return users_schedule


class ViewSchedule:

    # This gets automatically created inside __init__       __schedule_data_service: ScheduleDataService

    def __init__(self, schedule_data_service):
        self.__schedule_data_service = schedule_data_service

    def view_day(self, day_to_see, active_user):
        users_schedule = self.__schedule_data_service.load_users_schedule(active_user)


        to_view = []

        if day_to_see == "1":
            to_view.append("Monday")
        elif day_to_see == "2":
            to_view.append("Tuesday")
        elif day_to_see == "3":
            to_view.append("Wednesday")
        elif day_to_see == "4":
            to_view.append("Thursday")
        elif day_to_see == "5":
            to_view.append("Friday")
        elif day_to_see.lower() == "all":
            to_view = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
        else:
            logger.debug("Sorry that isn't a valid option please try again")
            logger.info(active_user + "failed to view " + day_to_see + " from their schedule due to incorrect input")
            pass

        for day in users_schedule.week:
            if day.name in to_view:
                logger.debug("")
                for session in day.sessions:
                    logger.debug("Day: " + day.name + " Class Code: " + session.code + " Class length: "
                             + session.length)
                logger.debug("")


active_user = "Bob"
day_to_see = 1

scheduleDataSvc = ScheduleDataService()
vs = ViewSchedule(scheduleDataSvc)

vs.view_day(day_to_see, active_user)
```

Comment: Also, you you can't combine strings with ``\``.  You need ``+``.

Comment: Sorry about the missing imports. I will make sure to include those next time I post.

The \n is to print a new line (which it does) not to combine strings. When combining strings I am using +.

Comment: No worries.  I was meaning this bit: `users_object_path = root / "user_objects" / active_user`